# GAPI - Google Analytics Sampling.

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the GAPI API to access Google Analytics rather than do it myself directly (I know slightly lazy...). I've had a look at the class file but I can't see any built-in function for checking sampling. I was wondering if anyone who has used it has found a way to check if the results being returned are being sampled.

This is the code I am using.

```
    $this->load->config('gapi');

    $params = array('client_email' => $this->config->item('account_email'),
        'key_file' => $this->config->item('p12_key'));
    $this->load->library('gapi', $params);

    $this->gapi->requestReportData(
        $this->config->item('ga_profile_id'), //reportID
        array('date', 'transactionId', 'campaign'), //Dimensions
        array('transactionRevenue'), //Metrics
        '', //Sort Metric
        'medium==email', //Filters
        date('Y-m-01'), //Start Date
        date('Y-m-d'), //End Date
        1,
        500
    );

    $results = $this->gapi->getResults();
```

My plan is to run the report for a given date range, check to see if the data is sampled and if true, split the query into small parts to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`v3`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#sampleSize) API has 2 sampling-related response fields:

- `Sample Size`: number of data entries used
- `Sample Space`: number of data entries available

So if you do `Sample Size` / `Sample Space` you have your sampling ratio.

The [`v4`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportData.FIELDS.samples_read_counts) API has the same but named differently:

- `samplesReadCounts`: number of data entries used
- `samplingSpaceSizes`: number of data entries available

So if you do `samplesReadCounts` / `samplingSpaceSizes` you have your sampling ratio.

If `gapi` doesn't expose these fields in the response, then you should change API client (eg [use the official client](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php))

Comment: Using Hello Analytics seems like a good way to go actually. I did not see that they had their own. Thanks!